# Shortcode show error while editing post

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I have created a shortcode to show plugin template through Post When I am Add and view Post its Work well but when I am returning to edit post the page of the editor was not showing there only and a blank page appears.

This is my Shortcode

```
function show_template($attr)
{
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(

        'temp' => ''

    ), $attr );

    ob_start();
    $temp_id=$args['temp'];
    include('lib/show-template.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_action( 'init', 'testing_shortcode' );
 
function testing_shortcode()
{
    add_shortcode( 'thewisher', 'show_template' );
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing output buffering like that? Does it work if you do a test by removing the output buffering?

Comment: Is this the classic editor or gutenberg?

Comment: This is Gutenberg and I am new in this so I don't know to do for this

Comment: What is inside `lib/show-template.php`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I am passing $temp_id through shortcode to get data from the database to show in my post

Comment: Have you enabled debugging (https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) in your wp-config.php? What does the error_log say (in /wp-content directory)?